# Unable to change the input data type dynamically in table row using angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a table and its contains 2 fields. I need to add the row each time while clicking the "Add button" which contain 2 fields. The one is dropdown and another one is value field. I have to change the data type of value field based on dropdown selection dynamically.

Issue:

My issue is while changing the dropdown value in one row, the value field datatype is changing in all the rows.

Expected:
While changing the dropdown value in one row, the value field datatype should change in that row only.

```
 <button (click)="AddCondition()" mat-raised-button type="button">Add Condition</span></button>

 <table class="table">
     <tbody>
         <div>
             <mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="80px" >
                        <tr *ngFor="let row of formGroup.get('rows')?.controls;let i = index;" >
                            <td>
                                <mat-grid-tile>
                                    <mat-form-field class="dynamictablecell">
                                        <mat-label>Select Attribute</mat-label>
                                        <mat-select [formControl]="row.get('attribute1')" (selectionChange)="TOnChangeAttribute(row.get('attribute1').value.proname)">
                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let data of AttributeType;" [value]="data">
                                                {{ data.proid }}
                                            </mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field> 
                                </mat-grid-tile>                   
                            </td>

                            <td *ngIf="showvaluefield">
                               <mat-grid-tile>   
                                    <mat-form-field class="dynamictablecell">
                                        <mat-label>Value</mat-label>
                                         <input type="{{fieldvalue}}" value="fieldvalue" autocomplete="off" [formControl]="row.get('value')" matInput>   
                                    </mat-form-field>                                    
                                </mat-grid-tile> 
                            </td> 
                         </tr>
                 </mat-grid-list>  
           </div>
       </tbody>
  </table>

  ngOnInit() { 
   this.createForm();
   this.formGroup.addControl('rows', this.rows);
  }

  createForm() {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      'attribute1':[null],
      'value':[null], 
    });
    this.rows = this.formBuilder.array([]);
  }

  createItemFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      attribute1:null,
      value:null,
    });
  }

  AddCondition(){
    this.rows.push(this.createItemFormGroup());
  }

  TOnChangeAttribute(datatype){
    this.fieldvalue= datatype; //number,text,date
  }
```

Anyone help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Here is is demo hope will help https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-from-array-demo

Comment: @SantoshShinde My issue is while changing the data type

Answer (score 1):

you has

```
<input type="{{fieldvalue}}"..>
```

And fieldValue is an unique variable, this is the reason because when you change on option, all the "types" change

You can use some like

```
<input [type]="row.get('attribute1').value.proname"...>
```

And remove the "ugly" function `(selectionChange)="TOnChangeAttribute(row.get('attribute1').value.proname)"`

**Update** if we need clean the field, really you need use the (selectionChange) event. If we use a "reference variable" we can write no code in the .ts, just some like `(selectionChange)="field.setValue('')"`

```
 <tr *ngFor="let row of formGroup.get('rows')?.controls;let i = index;" >
    <td>
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-form-field class="dynamictablecell">
                ...
                <!--see the (selectionChange)--->
                <mat-select [formControl]="row.get('attribute1')" 
                    (selectionChange)="field.setValue('')">
                     ....
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field> 
        </mat-grid-tile>                   
    </td>

    <td *ngIf="showvaluefield">
       <mat-grid-tile>   
            <mat-form-field class="dynamictablecell">
                 ...
                 <!--see the #field -->
                 <input #field [type]="row.get('attribute1').value.proname"...>   
            </mat-form-field>                                    
        </mat-grid-tile> 
    </td> 
 </tr>
```

Comment: while changing dropdown values, I need to clear the input value field each time. can you help me out on this? @Eliseo

Comment: Then, really you need use the (selectionChange) event. I think (I don't check the code) that if you use a "reference variable" you can write no code in the .ts, just some like `(selectionChange)="field.setValue('')"`. See in the updated answer the use of reference variable